# How to reverse the transformation of an affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Beginner question here... I'm a little unclear on how to go about reversing a transformation of a matrix from the format of Ax=b (or if it's possible for that matter).

I started out with a 6x6 matrix `A` and target vector `b`, I can compute the missing vector using `Ax=b`

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 7 & 9\\
1 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 7 & 4\\
2 & 6 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 7\\
1 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 0\\
9 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]x=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\3 \\ 2 \\ 4 \\ 1 \\ 5\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
I then applied the points of the solved vector `x` to my dataset using an affine transformation and applied it with `geopandas.series.affine_transform` feeding in the 6 points of `x`

The points where then shifted around and added noise. How can I take the newly mapped points, and reverse the transformation so I can determine how much shift has occurred from the original location of the points?

To be more clear perhaps, I've transformed the location of some geospatial points. The points make up matrix `A`. The points were then given some random noise and shifted location. I want to reverse the transformation of these new points to see how far off they are from the original location by applying the transformation calculated from `Ax=b`

How do I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Not all matrices are invertible. You can calculate the inverse using row reduction though so it's relatively simple when it's possible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number